# Trying to print a struct element but getting blank. - C

Tags: c, string, printing, struct, format

I have a `struct person` that has the following elements, defined in `data.h`

```
typedef struct person{
    char firstName[20];
    char familyName[20];
    char telephoneNum[20];
    int type; // 0 = student / 1 = employee;
}newPerson;
```

I created an array of `person[MAX_PERSONS]` that is initialized in my `menu()` function. I then have an `addFirstName(newPerson pers)` function. However when I try to test print format using my `printFormat(newPerson pers)`function, I get blank, instead of the inputted name.

I have included the menu(), addFirstname(newPerson pers), and printFormat(newPerson pers) function below. I was wondering if anyone could tell me the reason for this. Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
int menu(){
    int num = 0;
    newPerson person[MAX_PERSONS]; 
    int option; // for user input for menu
    printf("\n\tPlease choose one of the following options to continue (0-9): ");   
    scanf("%d", &option );
    printf("\n\tYou selected %d\n", option);

    if (option == 0){ //program will close
        printf("\tProgram will now close.\n");
        exit(1);
    }   

    if (option == 1){ //program will ask for name input 
        addRecord(person[num]);
        printFormat(person[num]);
        char choice[0];
        printf("\n\t\tWould you like to enter another record? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%s", choice);    
        if (choice[0] == 'y'){
            num++;
            addRecord(person[num]);

        }
        if (choice[0] == 'n'){
            num++;
            mainMenu();
        }               
            /*

            IF YES, THEN NUM++
            THEN RUN ADDRECORD(PERSONNUM) AGAIN.    

            IF NO, THEN RETURN TO MAIN MENU.
            PRINTMENU
            THEN RUN MENU AGAIN
        */  
    }

    printf("\n\tNot a valid option, please try again // THE END OF MENU FUNCTION\n");
    return 0;
}

void addFirstName(newPerson pers){
    char firstName[20];
    printf("\n\tEnter first Name: ");
    scanf("%20s", firstName);
    strcpy(pers.firstName, firstName);
    printf("\n\tThe name entered is %s", pers.firstName);
}


void printFormat(newPerson pers){
    printf("\t\tThe name is %s", pers.firstName);
}
```

Comment: Do not ignore the return value of `scanf()`. Also, `scanf("%20s", firstName);` is wrong, it should be `scanf("%19s", firstName);` and you don't need a temporary buffer you can directly `scanf("%19s", fpers.firstName);` and avoid `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you pass the structure to `addFirstName` *by value* meaning that the function receives a *copy* of the structure. And changing a copy will of course not change the original.

While C does not support passing arguments *by reference*, it can be emulated using pointers. So change the `addFirstName` function to receive a *pointer* to the structure as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your big problem is that you are passing structures by value instead of by pointers. This result in that you change copies of original objects inside your function `addFirstName` and not the original object. You should declare it as:

```
void addFirstName( newPerson* pers);
void printFormat( newPerson* pers);
```

---

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call_by_value(int x) {
    printf("Inside call_by_value x = %d before adding 10.\n", x);
    x += 10;
    printf("Inside call_by_value x = %d after adding 10.\n", x);
}

int main() {
    int a=10;

    printf("a = %d before function call_by_value.\n", a);
    call_by_value(a);
    printf("a = %d after function call_by_value.\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

this will produce:

```
a = 10 before function call_by_value.
Inside call_by_value x = 10 before adding 10.
Inside call_by_value x = 20 after adding 10.
a = 10 after function call_by_value.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, for the printFormat function, would I have to change the function from `pers.firstName` to something else? I tried `&pers.firstName` but I then receive this error `request for member ‘firstName’ in something not a structure or union`

Comment: sorry, pers.firstName is not function, what do you mean?